Why is there 2.27V on the drain terminal of M1?
I have a circuit I am making to either switch two capacitors C1, C2 in parallel or in series. The intended behavior is when V3, V1 = 0V, V2 = 5V; they should be connected in series and the opposite voltages to be connected in parallel.
Both capacitors C1, C2 have an initial voltage of 5V.
As the title suggests, why is there 2.27V on the drain pin of M1? I believe this is causing a forward bias across M6's body-diode causing unintended behaviour.
I tried adding diode on the drain pin of M6, but this causes an unwanted voltage drop. (I want to maximize performance).
I have not formally taken any courses yet in regards to the operation of didoes and MOSFETS, I am making this for fun and to learn (I am still a student).
Any explanations and suggestions would be much appreciated =)
EDIT: I suppose a more fitting title would be "Why is there 7V on the positive terminal of C2?"


What is the intent of this circuit?  I.e. what is is trying to accomplish by rearranging the capacitors?  There is no voltage source I can see that interacts with the "meat" of your circuit. The schematic is extraordinarily difficult to read for having so few components.

@vir
The intent is to just power the load (R5) and to learn.
The capacitors have an initial charge of 5V. (Those are the only things driving the circuit).
Apologies for the schematic.

Try swapping the drain and source of M6 to reverse-bias the body diode.

@vir  I think this is effectively what they're trying to do, but using MOSFETs instead of the ideal switches.  https://i.sstatic.net/50s5vaHO.png  https://i.sstatic.net/JNOmtX2C.png

How ideal do you need this to work?  Using discrete MOSFETs for this has its limitations.

@SteKulov What you showed there in the images is the intended behaviour, thanks. Hmm, I suppose as ideal as we can!
Edit: Curious on what the main limitations are here.

I'll start with the initial question before getting to your design and how it relates to your goal.

As the title suggests, why is there 2.27V on the drain pin of M1? I
believe this is causing a forward bias across M6's body-diode causing
unintended behaviour.
EDIT: I suppose a more fitting title would be "Why is there 7V on the
positive terminal of C2?"

You are indeed correct this is due to the body diode.  I redrew your schematic with [more] ideal switches to clarify what you're trying to do.  When you want the capacitors in series, then S2 is ON and S1 & S3 are OFF.  When you want them in parallel, then the S2 is OFF and S1 & S3 are ON.  These screenshots show the intended behavior of the discharging of the initially charged capacitors in each mode.


We can start simplifying the schematic in steps to reduce it into an equivalent circuit.  You are having an issue when in series mode, so let's just focus on that.  S3 is OFF, so let's remove it.  S1 is ON so let's replace it with the IRF7220 with its gate tied to ground.  S2 is meant to be OFF, but the body diode is conducting so let's replace it with a diode using the IRF7220's body diode parameters Is=168p Rs=6m.  If we simulate the DC operating point .op of this circuit, we get the 7.055V at the load just like in your original circuit.

Now, let's start simplifying it as follows (see image below to follow along):

Replace the MOSFET with its equivalent Rds(on) which is 12.25mΩ. Replace the body diode with its equivalent series resistance of 9.25mΩ.  For the DC operating point, initialized capacitors in LTspice are equivalent to a DC voltage source equal to the initial capacitor voltage along with a 1mΩ resistor in series.  Replace each capacitor with this equivalent.

Combine the 12.25mΩ and 1mΩ in series into 13.25mΩ.

Perform a source transformation of the 13.25mΩ resistor and series voltage source to get a current source of 377.36A and a parallel 13.25mΩ resistor.

Combine the 13.25mΩ and 9.25mΩ resistors into a parallel equivalent of 5.447mΩ.

Perform a source transformation of the 377.36A current source and parallel 5.447mΩ resistor into a 2.0555V voltage source and 5.447mΩ series resistor.

Swap the 2.0555V voltage source and 1mΩ resistor so the two voltage sources are next to each other and two resistors are next to each other.

Add the voltage sources together and add the resistors together to get the final circuit of a 7.0555V voltage source and 6.447mΩ series resistor.



Notice how the voltage at the load always remains at 7.055V.  This illustrates that all these circuits are indeed equivalent to each other.

Now, onto your design goal:

I have a circuit I am making to either switch two capacitors C1, C2 in
parallel or in series.

There are two main caveats when working with discrete MOSFETs, versus those ideal SPICE switch elements I used above.  The first we already explored, which is the body diode.  This can be mitigated by putting two of the same MOSFET in series but with their sources and gates tied together such that the body diodes point counter to each other.  The penalty there is that you have to deal with double the Rds(on).
The other difference can be seen by noticing that the discrete MOSFET has 3 terminals, while those ideal switch elements have 4 terminals.  The difference is that in the MOSFET, one of the control terminals is shared with one of the switch terminals.  This is the source pin.  What this means is that your control signal is inherently referenced to the signal/voltage you are switching.  This makes the switching of analog signals somewhat complicated.  Normally, you use a discrete N-channel MOSFET for "low-side" switching where a typical scenario would be the source pin fixed at ground, the gate voltage also referenced to ground, and the load at the drain.  This is the case with S3 above, so S3 can easily be replaced with an N-channel MOSFET.  You use a P-channel MOSFET for "high-side" switching where the source pin is fixed to some supply voltage higher than ground, the gate is referenced to this voltage, and the load is also at the drain.  For both of these cases, the source pin is fixed at the same voltage and doesn't move around.  If you look at S1 and S2 in the circuit, this is not the case...so what do you do?
The typical solution for this is something you cannot do with discrete parts.  This would be using a "CMOS switch" (aka "transmission gate", aka "analog switch") integrated circuit.  MOSFETs on integrated circuits have 4-terminals, so they can perform this task and you can get 5V-operable ones at sub-1ohm ON resistance.  Even though the control signals are somewhat decoupled from the switch terminals, they aren't fully.  A P-channel is still better at passing stuff closer to "high-side" and N-channel is still better at passing stuff closer to "low-side".  So what they do in a CMOS switch is put both in parallel so they work together (C = complementary) to get you a somewhat constant ON resistance throughout the operating voltage range.  Here is what a plot of the ON resistance of a CMOS switch typically looks like (taken from the datasheet of the part linked above).

From left to right you move from the N-channel being the only one ON, then the P-channel kicks in so they work together in the middle region, and then the N-channel turns off so it's just the P-channel in that final region.

Having said all that, you can still try to make something close using discrete parts but it won't follow the ideal discharge profile exactly.  It will have some hiccups in it due to the MOSFETs' threshold voltages being hit as the voltage across the capacitors and the load change.  For example, we can use pretty much your same implementation except we add a 2nd P-channel MOSFET to prevent your body diode problem.  If we compare this implementation versus the ideal one in both modes, you can see a hiccup occur right around the threshold voltage of the IRF7220 Vto=-0.75.  This is when M5 turns off, breaking the series connection of the capacitors and stopping their discharge (except through the leakage path through M1's body diode).


You can see this point change if you alter the threshold voltage parameter of the IRF7220, as shown here:

Therefore, the best way to optimize this circuit would be to select P-channel MOSFETs with as low as threshold as possible (which looks like you already tried to do).

Lastly, I should mention that another way to do something like this with discrete parts is to use N-channel MOSFETs with a boosted gate driver.  This driver is used to generate a control voltage that's always higher than the signal at the source pin (plus the threshold voltage).  This is what switch-mode power supplies do, since it allows them to use the lower Rds(on) you get with N-channel MOSFETs.  For example, if you replaced your P-channels with N-channels and drove them with a 10V and 0V instead of 5V and 0V you would get these plots which line up with the ideal quite well.



Wow, amazing! I sincerely appreciate the time and effort you spent on this thorough, well-crafted answer.

@Skeeter4life Sure, no problem. Sorry it took so long. I started drafting an answer back when you posted the question, but got sidetracked when I had to go on a trip. When I came back it was on my list of things to do but never got enough time until now so I could write a full non-half-assed answer. I learned a few things myself when writing too. Anyway, glad the info is still useful even after it being so long after you made the question.
